# Regex to capture everything if word is detected

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture this url `https://www.example.com/admin`

I currently use this rule which matches everything unfortunately

`(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?`

my question is how can I match every URL that has `/admin` in it for example `/admin/a/1`, `/admin/2/b`

Comment: Use `^(https?:\/\/)?\S*\/admin(\/.*)?$`

Comment: @anubhava, perfect you want to add as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex to match URLs that either end with `/admin` or have `/admin/` in them:

```bash
^(https?:\/\/)?\S*\/admin(\/.*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1UYAy/2)

You may want to avoid capture groups and use all non-capture groups:

```bash
^(?:https?:\/\/)?\S*\/admin(?:\/\S*)?$
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(https?:\/\/)?`: Match optional `http://` or `https://`
- `\S*`: Match 0 or more non-whitespaces
- `\/admin`: Match `/admin`
- `(\/\S*)?`: Optionally match `/` followed by any non-whitespace text
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)\Wadmin\W.+
```